# Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable): Tasks are started twice?

Tags: c#, async-await

I just stumbled upon one of the overloads of [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx), the one that takes an IEnumerable as parameter

```
public static Task WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks)
```

I thought I'd try this function with the following short program.

In a Test class:

```
// contains the task numbers that has been run
private HashSet<int> completedTasks = new HashSet<int>();

// async function. waits a while and marks that it has been run:
async Task<int> Calculate(int taskNr)
{
     string msg = completedTasks.Contains(taskNr) ?
         "This task has been run before" :
         "This is the first time this task runs";
    Console.WriteLine($"Start task {i} {msg}");

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

    Console.WriteLine($"Finished task {taskNr}");
    // mark that this task has been run:
    completedTasks.Add(taskNr);
    return i;
}

// async test function that uses Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable)
public async Task TestAsync()
{
    Console.Write("Create the task enumerators... ");
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
        .Select(i => Calculate(i));
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");

    Console.WriteLine("Start Tasks and await");
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting. Results:");

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
    }
}
```

Finally the main program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var testClass = new TestClass();
     Task t = Task.Run(() => testClass.TestAsync());
     t.Wait();
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Create the task enumerators... Done!
Start Tasks and wait
Start task 1 This is the first time this task runs
Start task 2 This is the first time this task runs
Start task 3 This is the first time this task runs
Finished task 2
Finished task 3
Finished task 1
Finished waiting. Results:
Start task 1 This task has been run before
Finished task 1
1
Start task 2 This task has been run before
Finished task 2
2
Start task 3 This task has been run before
Finished task 3
3
```

**Apparently each task is run twice!** What am I doing wrong?

Even stranger: if I enumerate over the sequence of Tasks using `ToList()` before the Task.Whenall, the function works as expected!

Comment: "Note that this function is not async, and it is not awaitable" - it *is* awaitable. A function doesn't have to be marked as `async` to be awaitable - it just has to return something that follows the awaitable-awaiter pattern. And `Task` is *the* poster child for the pattern.

Comment: Sprry, that was my first version. Later I realised that could be the problem and I changed everything into async-await. Corrected the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is **deferred** execution. Change this line

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .Select(i => Calculate(i));
```

to

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .Select(i => Calculate(i)).ToList();
```

`Select()` does not *execute* the "query" immediatly, but returns an enumerator. Only if you use this enumerator to iterate through the tasks, the inner lambda is called for the sequence 1...3.
In your version, every time you iterate through `tasks`, `Calculate(i)` is called again and new tasks are created.
With `.ToList()` the enumerator is executed once and the resulting sequence of `Task<int>` is stored in a `List<Task<int>>` (and not generated again when that list is enumerated a second time).

---

When you call `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` this method iterates through `tasks` and thereby starts each task. When you later iterate again (with your `foreach` loop to output the result), the query is executed **again** and thereby new tasks are started.

Comment: Indeed your solution works, as I wrote at the end of the question. However, using deferred execution I'd expected it to be executed when Task.Whenall enumerated the sequence, Apparently Task.WhenAll enumerates twice.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` does it once, then you do it again in the `for` loop.

Comment: "then you do it again" - Well, the Enumerator does it again ... :)